# I am getting an error while installing PATE from SYFT

Tags: pytorch

I am doing a Differential Privacy Course and have to work with syft. When running the below command, I encountered a error

I have already installed syft package required for the analysis. And I am working in Anaconda on Windows 10

```
from syft.frameworks.torch.differential_privacy import pate
```

WARNING:tf_encrypted:Falling back to insecure randomness since the required custom op could not be found for the installed version of TensorFlow (1.13.1). Fix this by compiling custom ops.

Answer (score 1):

It is not an error it is a warning. It comes from tf_encrypted which is used in tensorflow. The problem is that on Windows secure randomness is not supported (according to https://github.com/tf-encrypted/tf-encrypted/issues/513). And as you use PyTorch you can just ignore it.